# Как достать данные в int или в String из JSON (Java и json-simple)

Tags: java, json

Есть `JSONObject`, и от туда я могу достать информацию только в переменную типа `long`
При попытке прировнять значение из `JSONObject` к переменной типа `int` или `String`:

```
String idPost = (String)postJSON.get("id");
int count = (int) responseJSON.get("count");
```

Получаю ошибку `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

Я понимаю что `java` говорит, что нельзя из `long` в `String`, НО может вы знаете способ достать значение сразу в `String` или в `int`.

Comment: `Я понимаю что java говорит, что нельзя из long в String` - вы **точно** прочитали сообщение?

Comment: `int count = ((Long) responseJSON.get("count")).IntValue();` ?

Comment: java говорит, что нельзя  не из long в String, а из Long в Integer. Вы же сами скопировали текст исключения. Разумется, вы можете кастовать лонг к инту, но только в определенный момент вы получите отрицательный айди, потому как лонг больше, чем инт, следовательно инт никак не может корректно хранить значения лонг, если они выходят за его пределы

Answer (score 0):

У JSONObject есть свой get для всех примитивов и стрингов.  getInt, getString и т. д. Даже getJSONObject и getJSONArray. Используйте их вместо небезопасной возни с кастами